# office365 login at windows8 mobile app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-authentication, office365, windows-live-id

Im have implemented the Windows Live Id authentication to my app. It works pretty well, but now I would like to authenticate my company office365 with a similuar solution. I have searched through google but I could not find a way to do this. There is only four brandings: Messenger, Microsoft Account, SkyDrive and Outlook.

Has anyone done something similuar, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's is not possible to use your office 365 as `single sign on`. You must use your `Microsoft Account`, in this case your `Windows Live Id`. This [guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-wp8/?fb=sv-se) will show you how.

You can how ever make your own `authentication service` by puting your `Active Directory` in Windows Azure if you want to use that instead. This [guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/) show you how to set up the a `Active Directory` forest in Windows Azure.